# Object #<Server> has no method 'use' [Express+ShareJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, share

### Environment

- Express 3.2.4
- ShareJS 0.6.2
- OS X 10.8.3

---

### Goal

I am trying to get ShareJS running inside of an Express app.

---

### Problem

I get the following error on running `node app.js`:

```
/Users/eric/Documents/Projects/collabit/node_modules/share/src/server/index.coffee:52
      server.use(options.staticpath, connect["static"]("" + __dirname + "/../.
             ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'use'
    at Function.create.attach.attach (/Users/eric/Documents/Projects/collabit/node_modules/share/src/server/index.coffee:52:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eric/Documents/Projects/collabit/app.js:43:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I used the express cli interface to generate an app and was working with SocketIO just fine before deciding to swap in ShareJS.  I'm pretty sure my issue is how I'm crafting the server but I don't know enough to figure out how I *should* be creating the server object to keep the express functionality but allow ShareJS to attach.b

---

### Code

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , sharejs = require('share')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});

/**
 * ShareJS Code
 */

var options = {db: {type: 'none'}};
sharejs.server.attach(server, options);
```

---

### Question

What is the proper way to create my server object in order to allow ShareJS to attach to it while retaining the Express functionality.

---

### Thanks!

Thanks in advance for help and let me know if any additional information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. After a lot of trial and error this worked for me:

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
sharejs = require('share').server;

var app  = express();
var server = http.createServer(app); 

var options = {db:{type:'none'}}; // See docs for options. {type: 'redis'} to enable     persistance.

// Attach the sharejs REST and Socket.io interfaces to the server
sharejs.attach(app, options);

app.use(app.router);

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

server.listen(8000, function () {
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('share.html');
});
```

Then in views/share.html I had the standard example html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajaxorg.github.com/ace/build/src/ace.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/channel/bcsocket.js"></script>
    <script src="/share/share.js"></script>
    <script src="/share/ace.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");

            sharejs.open('hello', 'text', 'http://localhost:8000/channel', function (error, doc) {
                doc.attach_ace(editor);
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #editor {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did indeed fix it!  I wonder why the documentation is specifically different.  Oh well, for your help!

Comment: I keep seeing 'sharejs has no method attach'. Do oyu know why this would be? Driving me crazy!

Comment: you need to use version 0.6.3 instead of 0.7.*

Comment: is there a reason you used a cdn for ace.js but also referenced it locally?

Comment: If I remember correctly they are two separate things. The ace editor (loaded via a cdn)  and the code to link sharejs to the ace editor